# cmd+shift+i doesn't work

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder

I am following a guide where it says to press cmd+shift+i to change an object proprieties in interface builder.
But pressing this shortcut it just has the effect to make  xcode build the project.
So I can't change an object proprieties (like a pushbutton or label).
How to do this with xcode4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Xcode -> Preferences -> Key Bindings`
You'll see all hotkeys in your Xcode and you'll be able to set your own if you want.

To change properties of object in IB open Utilities panel (use `alt+cmd+0` hotkey or press a button in top-right corner of Xcode) [image]

Then choose Attributes/Size Inspector or another one, it depends on properties you need to change